# Form Validation not working properly in codeigniter

Tags: php

Explanation :-
    It directly goes to the else part without executing the validation part.
    I have added 'form_validation' library and 'form' helper in autoload.php.
    Register.php is containing the view part.
    Main_Controller.php is containing the function user_register.
    I have tried both ways : 
1. set_rules()
2. form_validation.php (external file)

View-part:

```
    <?php include('Header.php'); ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>


       <html>
        <head>
          <title>User Registration</title>
        </head>
        <body>

        <div class="container" style="margin-top:20px;border:1px solid black;width:50%;">
        <h1>Register Here</h1>

         <?php echo form_open('Main_Controller/user_register'); ?>
         <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Name">Name:</label>
           <?php echo form_input(['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Enter Name','name'=>'Full_Name','value'=>set_value('Full_Name')]);  ?>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6" style="margin-top:40px;">
           <?php  echo form_error('Full_Name');  ?>
          </div>
          </div>
         <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-6">`enter code here`
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>

           <?php  echo form_input(['class'=>'form-control','type'=>'text','placeholder'=>'Enter Email',
           'name'=>'Email','value'=>set_value('Email')]); ?>
           </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-6" style="margin-top:40px;">
           <?php  echo form_error('Email');  ?>
          </div>
          </div>
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Mobile">Mobile No:</label>
           <?php echo form_input(['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Enter Mobile No','name'=>'Mobile',
           'value'=>set_value('Mobile')]);  ?>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6" style="margin-top:40px;">
           <?php  echo form_error('Mobile');  ?>
          </div>
          </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Employee_Id">Employee Id:</label>
                <?php echo form_input(['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Enter Employee Id',
                'name'=>'Employee_Id','value'=>set_value('Employee_Id')]);  ?>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6" style="margin-top:40px;">
            <?php  echo form_error('Employee_Id'); ?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Username">Username:</label>
              <?php echo form_input(['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Enter Username','name'=>'  Username','value'=>set_value('Username')]);  ?>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6" style="margin-top:40px;">
            <?php  echo form_error('Username');  ?>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="pwd">Password:</label> 
              <?php  echo form_password(['class'=>'form-control','type'=>'password','placeholder'=>'Enter Password','name'=>'Password','value'=>set_value('Password')]); ?>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6" style="margin-top:40px;">
           <?php  echo form_error('Password');  ?>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Confirm Password">Confirm Password:</label> 
              <?php  echo form_password(['class'=>'form-control','type'=>'password','placeholder'=>'Enter Confirm Password','name'=>'Confirm_Password','value'=>set_value('Confirm_Password')]); ?>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6" style="margin-top:40px;">
            <?php  echo form_error('Confirm_Password');  ?>
          </div>
        </div>
         <?php  echo form_submit(['type'=>'submit','class'=>'btn btn-primary','value'=>'Submit']);  ?>
         <?php  echo form_reset(['type'=>'reset','class'=>'btn btn-default','value'=>'Reset']);  ?> 
         <br><br>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>

        Controller (Main_Controller) :-

            public function user_register()
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('Full_Name','Full Name','required|alpha');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('Email','Email','required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('Mobile','Mobile Number','required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('Employee_Id','Employee Id','required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('Username','Username','required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('Password','Password','required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('Confirm_Password','Confirm Pssword','required');
                $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="text-danger">','</div>');
                //$this->load->view('');
                if($this->form_validation->run())
                {
                    $post=$this->input->post();
                    $this->load->model('My_Model');
                    if($this->My_Model->reg($post))
                    {
                        echo "Registration Successfull";
                    }   
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Registration Failed"; 
                    }
                 }//if
                else
                {
                return redirect('Main_Controller/register');
                }
            }//function
```

Comment: Did you load the form_validation library?

Comment: yes..i have loaded form_validation library.

Comment: what do you expect from your above code? without doing validation_errors();

Comment: Yeah..i forgot to do that..thank you

Answer (score 0):

redirecting after form validation clears the validation errors. 
try this

```
if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
    echo "Registration Successfull";
} else {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', validation_errors());
    redirect('Main_Controller/register');
}
```